# Stop function after using callback

Tags: node.js

How to make callback to act like return inside function.

```
frontendProcessor.validateJSON = function(json, callback) {
if(!json) {
    callback("Validate JSON: Error, empty JSON variable", null);
} else {
    try {           
        var newJson = JSON.parse(json);
    } catch(err) {          
        callback("Validate JSON: Error, Something is wrong with JSON.", null);          
    };
    callback(null, newJson);
};
};
```

If error will be caught, I would like to callback function and stop frontendProcessor.validateJSON function from continue it's processing. Any right way to do it, or just tricky ways?

Comment: Can you please specify which function you want to stop? Callback one? Or parent one which called callback?

Comment: frontendProcessor.validateJSON

Comment: just call empty return statement after callback. It will stop func execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the other callback, and you could always throw an error if parsing the JSON is somehow critical to the app

```
frontendProcessor.validateJSON = function(json, callback) {
    if(!json) {
        callback("Validate JSON: Error, empty JSON variable", null);
    } else {
        try {           
            var newJson = JSON.parse(json);
            callback(null, newJson);
        } catch(err) {          
            callback("Validate JSON: Error, Something is wrong with JSON.", null);
        };
    };
};

frontendProcessor.validateJSON(json, function(err, result) {
    if (err != null) {
        var err = new Error(err);
        throw err;
    }

    // use result

});
```

Comment: I've made this mistake before - inevitably, `callback` will error inside the `try`, causing it to be called a second time.  Calling the same callback twice tends to lead to all sorts of hard-to-debug bugs.